# Google Sheets Formula help: IF reference cell is BLANK, then cell is BLANK

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

OK the solution should be simple... like   `=IF(AG3 = "", "")`
but I am unable to add the clause to my current formula as seen below: Any suggestions?

```
=IF(

IF(AF3 <> "y",

SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!Q$3:U, 4, 0), 0), 
     IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!V$3:Z, 4, 0), 0))

,"0")

 = "0", "", SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!Q$3:U, 4, 0), 0), 
     IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!V$3:Z, 4, 0), 0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your current formula is "FORMULA", you would have to do the following:

```
=IF(AG3="",,FORMULA)
```

Now replace FORMULA with your actual formula and you get

```
=IF(AG3="",,IF(

IF(AF3 <> "y",

SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!Q$3:U, 4, 0), 0), 
     IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!V$3:Z, 4, 0), 0))

,"0")

 = "0", "", SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!Q$3:U, 4, 0), 0), 
     IFNA(VLOOKUP($AG3, RICS_TimeClocks!V$3:Z, 4, 0), 0))))
```

Comment: I tired something similar, but this formula returns "-80" due to another formula in a helper column. Any way to "add" 80 as well to send it to "0" for a result of "" in the cell?

Comment: `Any way to "add" 80 as well to send it to "0" for a result of "" in the cell?` where do you want to add the 80?

Comment: Never mind! A night away to sleep has revealed the solution. As long as column AG="" everything works perfectly. It still had data while I was testing :/

Thanks for your help!